# R - Improving the performance of a simple loop

Tags: performance, r

I'm a beginner with R, so I'm having trouble thinking of things the "R way"...

I have this function:

```
upOneRow <- function(table, column) {
  for (i in 1:(nrow(table) - 1)) {
    table[i, column] = table [i + 1, column]
  }
  return(table)
}
```

It seems simple enough, and shouldn't take that long to run, but on a dataframe with ~300k rows, the time it takes to run is unreasonable.  What is the right way to approach this?

Comment: It's easier to help if you tell what your goals with the function are.  What do you want it to be able to do?

Comment: you might want to avoid using the variable table also because `table` is a function that has a specific use.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of the loop you could try something like this:

```
n <- nrow(table)
table[(1:(n-1)), column] <- table[(2:n), column];
```

to vectorize is the key

Comment: I don't think this gives the same output as what the OPs function does. Starting with a an input object of `table <- data.frame(x = 1:10)`, the OPs function yields: `[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 10` while your code yields `[1] 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`. The basic premise of your answer is on track though IMHO.

Comment: This should be: `table[1:(n-1), column] <- table[2:n, column]` to fit the OP's function.

Comment: @Chase, @P Lapointe: You both are right. I correct my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: Columns in a data.frame are also vectors which can be indexed with [,]

```
my.table <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y=10:1)
> my.table
  x y
1 1 5
2 2 4
3 3 3
4 4 2
5 5 1
my.table$y <-c(my.table[-1,"y"],NA) #move up one spot and pad with NA
> my.table
  x  y
1 1  4
2 2  3
3 3  2
4 4  1
5 5 NA
```

Now you function repeats the last data point at the end. If this is really what you want, pad with tail(x,1) instead of NA.

```
my.table$y <-c(my.table[-1,"y"],tail(my.table$y,1)) #pad with tail(x,1)
> my.table
  x y
1 1 4
2 2 3
3 3 2
4 4 1
5 5 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you're trying to "move up" one column of a data frame, with the first element going to the bottom. Then, It might be achieved as:

```
col <- table[, column]
table[, column] <- col[c(nrow(table), 1:(nrow(table)-1))]
```